# "The sum of vector spaces in the transversality condition need not be direct."

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology

I'm reading "Introduction to Differential Topology" by Brocker and Janich.

What other sum of vector spaces is there? I can see if we are trying to sum two identical spaces, it doesn't make much sense to construct $\mathcal{V} \oplus \mathcal{V}$, a set of ordered pairs. Instead we would want to just say $\mathcal{V} + \mathcal{V} = \mathcal{V}$. Is this what the author is referring to? If so, what name do we give the $(+)$ operator in the preceding sentence? $(\oplus)$ is called the "direct sum," for example.

Answer (score 1):

If we are given a vector space $X$ and two vector subspaces $V,W \subset X$, then $V+W = \{v+w \, | \, v \in V, w \in W\}$ is also a subspace. This kind of sum is what is used in studying transversality, where $X$ might be for example the tangent space of a differential manifold at some point, and $V,W$ might be tangent spaces of submanifolds passing through the same point. This sum will be a direct sum if and only if $V \cap W$ is the trivial subspace.

Comment: Interesting. So If I had $V = \mathbb{R}$ and $W = \mathbb{R}$, then $\mathbb{R} + \mathbb{R} = \mathbb{R}^2 \neq \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: $\mathbb{R} + \mathbb{R} = \mathbb{R}$ not $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Notice: in my answer, $V+W$ is only defined when $V,W$ were subspaces of a given vector space. If, say, you had asked about $V = \{(x,0) \, | \, x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ and $W = \{(0,y) \, | \, y \in \mathbb{R}\}$, then $V,W$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2 = \{(x,y) \, | \, x,y \in \mathbb{R}\}$, and $V + W = \mathbb{R}^2 = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I think part of the source of @Johnver's confusion is that there are two notions of direct sum, which we often conflate. The _external direct sum_ of two vector spaces $V$ and $W$ is the set of ordered pairs $\{(x,y): x\in V\text{ and }y\in W\}$, and is exactly the same as the direct product $V\times W$. The _internal direct sum_, on the other hand, is defined only when $V$ and $W$ are subspaces of a given vector space with $V\cap W=\{0\}$, and in that case is the same as the space $V+W$.